# Should I be concerned about my daughter talking to herself?

Tags: teen, pre-teen, anxiety, self-control

My daughter is 12 years old. She is an introvert and was having issues making friends in the past, but now she has a few friends in her school.

She keeps walking around the house (sometimes for an hour) talking to herself and I think making conversations in her mind. What I hear is just humming.

I asked her once what she was doing. In response, she laughed and said "nothing" and seemed to enjoy the attention I gave to her humming.

Since then I have not asked her about her humming and talking to herself as I don't want to encourage it.

I wonder if I should be concerned about that or if this is normal.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't be concerned at all. This is incredibly common, and not just in children. Many adults do it. Some internalise their voices, others externalise them.

You shouldn't do anything about this - it shouldn't change your behaviour towards your daughter, just keep on being a good parent, support her development, and don't get too concerned when she discovers new behaviours in her teenage years.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't be concerned. I believe that this is a healthy sign of development if anything. Introverted children can become discouraged if you express dismay at this, mayhaps even creating a rift.

Answer (score -4):

If your concerned about Schizophrenia this cannot be diagnosed until 21 first and foremost. You must also consider you and her dad's mental health history on both sides. Generally,  children will seek attention in any form possible. Just sit her down and have a general conversation with her. Ask her if she is okay, if she is bored or, if she would like to do something with you. However,  just as most have pointed out this can be normal behavior.  On a side note.. most adults speak and answer themselves because they do not trust others and, they confined in themselves.  This can come from trauma, failed friendships/ relationships.. ect.

Comment: There are some mighty big assumptions in your answer. SE expects authoritative answers, not opinion, so when strong or erroneous opinions are stated as facts, we ask for sources. Your statement about schizophrenia is incorrect, and, well, let’s just leave it at “You need reliable sources for this answer.”

Comment: You can **absolutely** be diagnosed before age 21. Early-onset schizophrenia is a thing.